# About the gradient vector

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The gradient vector of a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ is $$\nabla f=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right).$$
and usually, people say that the gradient vector tells you what is the direction you should take to increase the value of the function faster, but I can't relate this with taking the derivatives of the function, I mean what is the relation between the derivatives of $f$ and the direction that increases the function faster?

Comment: [See this answer I wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4002483/688539). It's an application in machine learning but it more or less captures the essnece of your quesiton

Comment: strictly speaking the gradient is not a vector, instead is a covector field

Comment: @janmarqz I wonder when elementary calculus / analysis classes will finally stop teaching this misconception.

Comment: @janmarqz: The differential $df$ is a covector field. The gradient $\nabla f$ is the vector field obtained by raising the index on $df$ using the metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the direction $v = (a,b)$, where $\|v\| = 1$.

Then the directional derivative in the direction $v$ is given by:
\begin{align*}
D_{v}f(x,y) = f'(x,y)v = \|\nabla f\|\|v\|\cos(\theta) = \|\nabla f\|\cos(\theta)
\end{align*}
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\nabla f$ and $v$.

It attains its maximum value when $\theta = 0$.

So $v$ which maximizes the directional derivative is in the same direction as $\nabla f$.

Hopefully this helps!